# Calculating days between two dates with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to develop a small Flutter app that calculates the number of days between two dates, using the following steps :

1. Ask the user to type the first date (Turkish notation; with whitespaces: "dd mm yyyy")
2. Ask the user to type the second date.

After that the program should calculates the number of days between the two dates and display it.

Comment: Hi; did this answer your question? You have not accepted it as an answer so if there is anything I can clarify please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Given `dateText` and `dateText2`, this will give you the days between:

```
var dateArray = dateText.split(' ');  // [d, m, y]
var date = new DateTime(int.parse(dateArray[2]), int.parse(dateArray[1]), int.parse(dateArray[0]));

var dateArray2 = dateText2.split(' ');
var date2 = new DateTime(int.parse(dateArray2[2]), int.parse(dateArray2[1]), int.parse(dateArray2[0]));

var daysBetween = date2.difference(date).inDays;
print(daysBetween);  // 365
```